# The file not showing up on Movie Clip Editor?

Tags: movie-clip-editor

[image]

My file just refuses to show up on the Movie Clip Editor workflow. I'm sure it must be something simple, but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

It was the start frame not set to where the playhead was.